# Automatically selecting element from QListView

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlistview

I have a QListView widget that contains a set of elements. I am trying to automatically select the last element, each time this QListView is updated (and to display it in the GUI).

What I want to do is something like this:

```
list_view_1  = QtWidgets.QListView()
element_list = QStandardItemModel(list_view_1)

element_list.appendRow(QStandardItem(element))
list_view_1.setModel(element_list)

list_view_1.setCurrentIndex(len(element_list))
```

The last command doesn't seem to work. I tried to look around for any previous posts but I couldn't find something that works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the index of the last element in the model you can use something like

```
index = element_list.index(element_list.rowCount()-1, 0)
list_view_1.setCurrentIndex(index)
```

But since you just created and added the item you could also do something like

```
item = QStandardItem(element)
element_list.appendRow(item)
list_view_1.setModel(element_list)

index = element_list.indexFromItem(item)
list_view_1.setCurrentIndex(index)
```